# Toast is not showing on React Query queryClient mutations onError callback function

Tags: react-query

I am using React-Query with Next.js, I want to showing toast message globally.
The toast is not showing, but console.log is printed on console window.

Has anyone experienced the same problem as me? Please guide me

```js
  const handleApiError = useApiError();

  const [queryClient] = React.useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            retry: 0,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            throwOnError: true,
            staleTime: 5 * 1000,
          },
          mutations: {
            retry: 0,
            onError: handleApiError,
          },
        },
      }),
  );

const useApiError = () => {
  const { showToast } = useToast();

  const handleApiError = (error: unknown) => {
    const message =
      ApiError.parsedErrorMessage(error as AxiosError) ?? TOAST_MESSAGE.fail;

    showToast({
      type: 'fail',
      message,
    });
  };

  return handleApiError;
};

export default useApiError;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { QueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: Infinity,
    },
  },
})

export default queryClient
```

Move your query client outside React.useState hook. You can create a separate file for that.Check the documentation.

[https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclient](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclient.)

Your example looks extremely coupled, your toast display should be handled by a React component, not a hook that manages the Api errors.

### Example

```
const Todos = () => {

  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery("todos", getTodos);

  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

  if (error) {
      showToast({
          type: 'fail',
          message: 'your message',
      });
  }

  return (<TodoList todos={data} />)
}
```